# Classe Abstrata X Interface

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface, classes-abstratas

Qual a diferença entre uma classe abstrata e uma interface?
Não entendo quando eu deveria utilizar uma ou outra.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse post, http://www.guj.com.br/java/102664-quando-usar-a-classe-abstrata-e-a-interface Deve te ajudar ;)

Comment: Neste post tem uma explicação detalhada: http://www.devmedia.com.br/interfaces-x-classes-abstratas/13337

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Uma classe abstrata pode conter lógica (código), enquanto que uma interface somente pode especificar quais os métodos ou propriedades (no caso de .NET) uma classe que implementa a interface deve definir. Entretanto nenhuma das duas pode ser usada para construir um objeto, para isso é necessário definir uma classe que derive da abstrata (mas que não seja abstrata) ou que implemente a interface.

Exemplo de classe abstrata:

```
abstract class MaquinaDeLavar
{
   public MaquinaDeLavar()
   {
      // Codigo para iniciar o objeto.
   }

   abstract public void Lavar();
   abstract public void Enxaguar(int tamanhoCarga);
   abstract public long Secar(int velocidade);
}
```

Comment: Costumo utilizar classe abstrata quando algum método implementado pode ser utilizado nas classes derivadas. Senão geralmente é Interface.

Comment: @bigown - grato pela edicao. Infelizmente nao tenho teclado PT-BR :)

Answer (score 27):

Para complementar a resposta do Otavio:

Aviso: herança (através de classes abstractas) não deve ser abusada! Algumas pessoas tendem a abusar de classes abstractas com um objectivo em mente: **reutilizar código**, que de outra forma seria repetido em classes concretas.

Isto esta errado! Herança deve ser usada em um e um só caso: quando existe uma relação **"é um tipo de"** entre a classe concreta e a abstracta. Por exemplo, "um gato *é um tipo de* animal" ou "um apartamento *é um tipo de* casa".

Quando pensar em usar classes abstractas e herança, lembre-se do LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle).
Este princípio diz que se uma classe `Derivada` deriva da classe `Base`, então qualquer código que use `Base` pode também usar uma instancia de `Derivada` sem efeitos surpreendentes.

Por exemplo, à primeira vista, pode parecer natural que `Quadrado` herde de `Rectângulo`. O quadrado *é um tipo de* rectângulo, em que a largura é sempre igual a altura.

De modo a manter esta propriedade, podes implementar a classe `Quadrado` assim:

```
public class Quadrado : Rectangulo
{    
    //propriedade herdada de rectangulo
    public override int Largura
    {
        get { return base.largura; }
        set 
        { 
            base.largura = value;
            base.altura = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora imagina o seguinte código:

```
public void Metodo(Rectangulo rect) {
  rect.Altura = 10;
  rect.Largura = 20;
  Console.WriteLine(rect.Altura);
}
```

Este código espera imprimir 10, porque ele mudou a altura do rectangulo para 10.
Mas se for substituído por um quadrado, então ele vai imprimir 20!! Este é um efeito inesperado! Então, apesar de no mundo real o quadrado ser um tipo de rectângulo, ele viola o principio LSP e não deve existir uma relação de herança entre os dois.

Fonte:
[Principio de Substituicao de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov)

Answer (score 16):

Complementando a resposta do pessoal.

### Classe abstrata

É um tipo de classe que somente pode ser herdada e não instanciada. De certa forma, pode-­se dizer que este tipo de classe é uma classe conceitual que pode definir funcionalidades para que as suas subclasses possam implementá-­las.
O conjunto de métodos na classe abstrata é obrigatoriedade, assim como a implementação nas suas subclasses. Em uma classe abstrata, os métodos declarados podem ser abstratos ou não, e suas implementações devem ser obrigatórias na subclasse.

### Interface

Define as operações que um objeto será obrigado a implementar. É importante lembrar que uma interface nunca contém implementação, ou seja, numa interface não se pode definir campos, pois os mesmos são uma implementação de um atributo objeto. A interface também não permite construtores, pois num construtor temos as instruções usadas para inicializar campos. Para podermos usar uma interface, devemos criar uma classe ou estrutura e herdar da interface. Com isso, é obrigatório implementar todos os métodos da interface.

### Conclusão

Uma classe abstrata pode conter métodos completos ou incompletos. Uma Interface pode conter apenas a assinatura de um método, mas nenhum corpo ou implementação. Portanto, em uma classe abstrata, pode-­se implementar métodos, mas em uma Interface, não. Uma classe abstrata pode conter campos, construtores, ou destrutores e aplicar propriedades. Uma interface não pode conter campos, construtores, ou destrutores. Pode possuir apenas a propriedade da assinatura, mas não a implementação. Uma classe abstrata não suporta múltiplas herança. Assim, uma classe pode implementar várias interfaces, mas apenas herdar de uma classe abstrata. Uma classe que implementa uma interface tem obrigatoriamente que implementar todos os métodos desta, mas o mesmo não é exigido no caso de uma classe abstrata. As classes abstratas são mais rápidas que as interfaces.

Comment: Ótima explicação.

Answer (score 11):

Uma classe abstrata, em C#, é uma classe que define um comportamento básico, mas não auto-suficiente. Por não ser suficiente, você precisa criar uma classe que herde dela para poder usá-la.

Não conheço nenhum exemplo de classe abstrata em C#. De fato, elas são bem raras no framework .NET.

Já uma interface não define comportamento. Uma interface é como se fosse um protocolo. Ela define a quais ações uma classe que a implementa deve responder, mas não diz como.

Exemplos comuns de interface são `IEnumerable` (que diz que uma classe deve ser enumerável) e `INotifyPropertyChanged` (que diz que uma classe deve enviar uma notificação quando suas propriedades são alteradas).

Note que, no C#, é convenção iniciar nomes de interfaces com um `I` maiúsculo.

Comment: André, corrija. Não são tão raras assim. Boa parte dos provedores possuem implantações em classes abstratas. (Role, Membership, User e etc)

Comment: Conforme o Cleiton disse as classes abstratas são muito utilizadas, acredito que mais ainda do que as Interfaces. Mas geralmente nós consumimos já classes concretas que herdam delas. Classes de banco de dados e controles são alguns exemplos destas classes. Geralmente usamos a implementação concreta. Quando se tenta fazer um biblioteca é que se acaba chegando nelas com mais frequencia.

Comment: Como eu disse, eu não conheço. Se sintam a vontade pra editar minha resposta e incrementá-la se quiserem. Afinal, são exemplos, que nunca são demais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

Para entender a diferença entre classes abstratas e Interfaces creio que será necessário recorrer a história a fim de elucidar como as coisas ocorreram.

Mesmo já existindo nos primórdios da criação da orientação a objeto, como smalltalk e outros, as interfaces foram criadas no Windows para poder suportar de forma mais simples , em 1992, o modelo de arquitetura da Microsoft chamado COM para Comunicação interprocessos (IPC) como são o DDE e OLE.

COM, COM+ e DCOM são evoluções de DDE e OLE. Corba é Concorrente do COM.

COM implementa a ABI, Application binary interface onde uma interface de uma aplicação externa possui um contrato ou uma "interface" para chamada a ser usada por outras aplicações. Esse contrato funciona como uma assinatura contendo os argumentos, tipos e resultado da função, além do GUID.

Como as classes abstratas não tinham e nem eram apropriadas porque não foram feitas para isso, por exemplo uma classe abstrata não possui GUID que é o identificador único de uma interface, identificador este que é requisito para se trabalhar com COM. Então as interfaces caíram como uma luva para se implementar COM.

Porém Interfaces também desempenham um papel semelhante à Classes Abstratas. Quando olhamos Interfaces pelo ponto de vista de Orientação a objetos, concluimos que em termos genéricos fazem exatamente a mesma coisa : Abstrair conceitos para futura implementação.

Por isso é difícil entender as diferenças e a pergunta poderia ser também formulada dessa forma : Porque disponibilizaram 2 formas de se abstrair implementações ? A resposta Srs. está na história do próprio Windows, **Interfaces foram implementadas no Sistema Operacional para servir ao COM.**

Mas já que interfaces servem também ao propósito de abstrair conceitos, porque não usá-la ? Então começaram a usá-la com esses objetivos, mas que não necessariamente faziam IPC (interprocess comunication) e COM e daí a semelhança com as classes abstratas.

O desconhecimento da história faz suscitar justificativas para uso de um em detrimento do outro, e a utilização em massa de um não denigre a utilização de outro. Ora se compararmos os dois sob o ponto de vista OO, vemos que as classes abstratas possuem até mais recursos que uma interface, como a possibilidade a criação de métodos, campos e estados, o que uma interface não pode. Então seria o caso de optarmos por Classes Abstratas ao invés de interfaces. Não é o caso também de se comparar em termos de desempenho, pois as classes concretas de ambas possuem a mesma forma de acesso aos métodos, via VMT (virtual methods table).

A não ser o fato de que a classe que implementa interface pode ter herança múltipla de Interfaces, e uma classe que implementa a classe abstrata não pode. Essa é a única distinção conceitual que vejo entre elas, diferença essa, diga-se de passagem, **pouquíssimas vezes usadas no dia a dia e na arquitetura de software não básico.**

**Concluindo :** Não há diferenças conceituais em se tratando dos objetivos a serem alcançados tanto pelo uso de interfaces quanto pelo uso de classes abstratas, quando NÃO estamos falando de IPC e COM.

Esses objetivos em comum são :

***Prover coesão, baixo acoplamento, independência de implementações para diferentes situações, abstração de conceitos.***

As diferenças ficam por conta de sintaxe, declarações, formas de uso impostas pelo compilador, liberação de memória e se vai trabalhar com COM ou não.

Portanto tendo em mente o objetivo de abstrair conceitos, tanto faz o uso de uma ou outra, com ligeira vantagem em utilizar classes abstratas por possuir maiores recursos.

Fontes : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Answer (score -1):

**Classe Abstrata**

É uma classe que serve de modelo para outras classes, mas ela mesma não deve ser instanciada. Por exemplo, a classe "veículo". Ela pode conter várias características de um carro, navio ou avião, porém ela mesma não se tornará algo concreto (instanciado). Já a classe "carro", que contém os atributos e métodos da classe "veículo", esta sim será instanciada.

**Interface**

A interface pode ser entendida como um tipo especial de classe abstrata, onde contém apenas atributos especiais (static e final) e todos os seus métodos são implicitamente abstract e public e não possuem corpo. Isso implica que as interfaces não poderão ser instanciadas e, portanto, não podem apresentar construtores; seus métodos também só terão a assinatura. Algo importante a ser dito é que a interface não precisa ser usada em situações de herança. Por exemplo, suponhamos que as classes A, B e C sejam herdeiras da classe abstrata Z. E queiramos atribuir apenas as classes B e C determinado comportamento. Se fosse feito pela classe abstrata Z todos herdariam, então resolvemos isso criando uma interface e a relacionamos apenas com B e C.

Só lembrando que todos os métodos abstratos, seja da classe abstrata ou da interface, terão de ser implementados pelas classes herdeiras.