# Interface ou Abstract?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, interface, classes-abstratas

Li vários conteúdos sobre este tema, até chegar nesse exemplo:

```
public interface Funcionario{  
      public void trabalha();  
      public void recebe(double salario);  
}
```

```
public abstract class Geek implements Funcionario{  
    public abstract void trabalha();  
    public abstract void recebe(double salario);  
    public void programa(){  
       System.out.println("import java.io.*; :) ");  
    }  
}  

public abstract class BusinessMan implements Funcionario{  
     public void trabalha(){  
         System.out.println("$$$");  
     }  
     public abstract void recebe(double salario);  
}
```

```
// programador é um geek e também um funcionário...  
public class Programador extends Geek{  
      private double salario;  
      public void trabalha(){  
           super.programa();  
      }  
      public void recebe(double salario){  
            this.salario = salario;  
      }  
}

/* analista também é um geek e um funcionário, mas que trabalha de maneira diferente ao programador*/  
public class Analista extends Geek{  
      private double salario;  
      public void trabalha(){  
           super.programa();  
           supervisionaProjeto();  
      }  
      public void recebe(double salario){  
            this.salario = salario;  
      }  
      private void supervisionaProjeto(){  
           System.out.println("Supervisiona");  
      }  
}  

public class Gerente extends BusinessMan{  
     private double salario;  
     private final double BONUS = 1000.0d;  
     public void recebe(double salario){  
         this.salario = salario + this.BONUS;  
     }  
}
```

```
public class Empresa{  
   public static void main(String[] args){  
      private Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[5];  
      funcionario[0] = new Programador();  
      funcionario[1] = new Programador();  
      funcionario[2] = new Analista();  
      funcionario[3] = new Programador();  
      funcionario[4] = new Gerente();  
      // faz alguma coisa...  
   }  
}
```

Fonte: http://www.guj.com.br/java/6854-classe-abstrata#38794

Eu mudei a `interface Funcionario` por uma classe abastrata, e fiz as outras classes, que antes implementavam, agora extenderem ela. Assim:

```
public abstract class Funcionario {
    public abstract void trabalha();
    public abstract void recebe(double salario);
}

public abstract class Geek extends Funcionario{
    @Override
    public abstract void trabalha();

    @Override
    public abstract void recebe(double salario);

    public void programa() {
        System.out.println("import java.io.*; :) ");
    }
}

public abstract class BusinesMan extends Funcionario {

    @Override
    public void trabalha() {
        System.out.println("$$$");
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void recebe(double salario);

}
```

Não houve modificação nenhuma ao compilar e rodar.

Minha pergunta é:
**Neste caso específico** muda alguma coisa com essas mudanças? Tem alguma funcionalidade que vou perder ou ganhar?

Obs.: não estou me referindo à desempenho. Estou me referindo a questão de manutenção ou complexidade, por exemplo, se mais tarde eu precisar adicionar mais algum tipo de funcionário, vai haver diferença nos dois casos?

Comment: Seria uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3603/classe-abstrata-x-interface, apesar da linguagem não ser a mesma?

Comment: A linguagem realmente não será o diferencial. Ambas seguem características muito semelhantes e a resposta de uma serviria para a outra linguagem neste caso. O que pode diferenciar uma da outra é que aqui tem uma caso concreto a ser analisado. Certamente a do C# complementa esta. Se é duplicata gostaria de mais alguma opinião.

Comment: Eu li essa pergunta e fiquei muita na dúvida em fazer a minha pergunta, mas não consegui obter a resposta nela para esse meu caso. Por isso fiz uma nova pergunta. Anyway as duas abordam o mesmo tema... Alguma sugestão para que eu possa editar a pergunta e ficar mais diferente da outra?

Comment: @Earendul provavelmente causaria mais problemas porque aí poderia invalidar as repostas. O que você acabou de dizer é fundamental para ajudar na decisão. Eu terminei de ler a outra e realmente acho que aqui pede e fora dado algo diferente.

Comment: @Earendul Pelo que você diz não dá para considerarmos duplicata mesmo. Vou manter nossos comentários aqui, como referência, caso alguém no futuro pense que é duplicata.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

À princípio não houve muita mudança. Interfaces normalmente são preferidas quando não há estado ou implementações, que é o seu caso. E isto é o mais importante a observar. **Esse caso** não demanda classes. Se o problema fosse outro eu pensaria diferente. Por isto é importante nunca ir atrás de boas práticas e analisar o problema específico. Entender o que você quer. Para isto é importante entender a diferença entre as duas.

Você até poderia ter uma limitação futura usando uma classe abstrata porque Java só permite herança "de verdade" de apenas uma classe. E qualquer classe que herde da classe abstrata `Funcionario` não poderá herdar de outra classe, só poderá implementar outras interfaces.

Na prática eu duvido que isto realmente seja um problema na maioria dos casos. Se você apenas implementar `Funcionario` nas classes descritas permitirá no futuro que você possa herdar de alguma classe (abstrata ou não) já que você só tinha implementado interfaces e nenhuma classe. Mas você vai modificar estas classes existentes para herdar de outra classe? Vai ferir o [princípio Open/Close](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)? E ele costuma ser importante nestes casos. Não digo que não exista situação em que isto pode ser interessante, mas em geral não é.

Existe algum motivo para preferir a classe abstrata? Se não encontrar um, eu ficaria com a interface. Em geral o motivo é que você precisa de estado. Mesmo se precisar de implementações, eu não sei se seria justificativa, ainda mais em Java 8 com os *[default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)*. A não ser que precise implementar "detalhes de implementação", ou seja, métodos privados.

Do jeito que `Funcionario` está descrito me parece estar declarando algumas características que um elemento que seja um funcionário de algum tipo deveria ter. O que é diferente de dizer que `Funcionario` contém definições importantes para todos que sejam funcionários. É a famosa diferença de **ser** e **ter**. Use classes quando as classes derivadas serão aquilo, neste caso, **são** funcionários. Ou use interfaces quando as classes derivadas apenas **têm** aquelas características, comportamentos definidos (mas não implementados).

Pelo nome pode ser tentador achar que `Geek` ou `Analista` **são** funcionários e não apenas possuem características de um funcionário. Mas o código mostra algo diferente. Por isto a especificação correta é importante para fazer a escolha correta. Talvez você saiba de algo que não sabemos.

Sobre isto pode aprender mais sobre no [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) (em inglês, como sempre, tá melhor) ([tem resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)).

Lembre-se que em tese é mais fácil transformar uma interface em classe abstrata se um dia isto for necessário do que o contrário. Na verdade, ambos vão dar trabalho e trazer riscos.

Realmente desempenho e outras questões técnicas são pouco importantes perto do problema de engenharia que você terá. Em geral é mais fácil adicionar interfaces. Você poderia ter vantagens na classe abstrata se quiser **implementar** ou modificar implementações existentes nela e que isto seja refletido automaticamente nas classes descendentes. Mas isto precisa ser feito com tanto cuidado que é preciso sempre questionar se vale à pena.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bom. Me lembrou da frase do professor: "Usar herança quando o objeto for um tipo especial de, e não um papel assumido por". Vou seguir seu conselho de "nunca ir atrás de boas práticas e analisar o problema específico".

Comment: Eu não chego demonizar boas práticas, demonizo o que as pessoas fazem com elas. Tornam-as como regras imutáveis, verdades universais. Aí é que elas não ajudam.

Comment: E acho que isso gera muitas desconfianças e inseguranças também. A gente acaba sempre pensando "será que to fazendo certo mesmo?".

Comment: E não tem muito o que fazer a não ser estudar, perguntar, praticar, procurar melhorar, enfim, obter experiência. Ah, e errar também, porque é errando que se aprende. Com 30 anos de experiência eu vivo errando.

Answer (score 7):

Conceitualmente não há diferença entre uma **interface** e uma **classe puramente abstrata**, isto é, com todos os métodos abstratos.

Com relação à mudanças, a classe abstrata permitiria implementar um método não abstrato a ser reusado nas subclasses.

Resumindo, classes abstratas ajudam se você tem um tipo genérico (superclasse) que é base para tipos mais específicos e especializados (subclasses).

Já interfaces são melhores como especificação do comportamento de um tipo. Não pense em interfaces para reuso de código.

Aliás, cuidado também quando utilizar herança para reaproveitar código. O preço a ser pago (alto acoplamento entre super e subclasses) pode ser muito caro. Sempre que puder, dê preferência à delegação.

## Abordagem mista

Você também pode usar interfaces e classes abstratas conjuntamente.

Exemplo:

```java
public interface Funcionario {  
      void trabalha();  
      void recebe(double salario);  
}

public abstract class FuncionarioAbstrato implements Funcionario {
    double salario;
    public abstract void recebe(double salario) {
        this.salario += salario;
    }
}
```

Considero esta abordagem mais flexível, pois caso algum dia surgisse um outro tipo de funcionário que não se encaixa na sua hierarquia de classes, basta implementar a interface numa implementação completamente nova.

## Segregação das Interfaces

Outra abordagem que pode ser útil a longo prazo é segregar as interfaces de forma que as ações sejam mais específicas.

Imagine que o sistema também passe a contar o dono no quadro de funcionários, por algum motivo qualquer. Porém, o dono não trabalha, ele apenas recebe.

Então você poderia ter um modelo assim:

```java
public interface Trabalhador {  
      void trabalha();  
}

public interface Recebedor {  
      void recebe(double salario);  
}

public abstract class RecebedorAbstrato implements Recebedor {
    double salario;
    public void recebe(double salario) {
        this.salario += salario;
    }
}

public class Programador extends RecebedorAbstrato implements Trabalhador {
    public void trabalha() {  
        System.out.println("import java.io.*; :) ");  
    }  
}

public class Dono extends RecebedorAbstrato {
    //nada além d ereceber
}
```

E se a diferença do Analista é simplesmente fazer algo a mais, poderia fazer assim:

```java
public class Analista extends Programador {
    public void trabalha() {  
        super.trabalha();
        System.out.println("Supervisiona");    
    }  
}
```

Bem, foram apenas algumas ideias. Não existe necessariamente uma modelagem mais correta, sempre depende do problema.

---

*Nota: assinaturas de métodos em interfaces não precisam do `public`, pois os métodos sempre são sempre públicos*

Comment: Perfeito. Me esclareceu bastante as idéias. Muito interessante os seus exemplos, vou até salvar o link pra consultas no futuro. Valeu.

Answer (score 4):

Bem classes abstratas e interfaces são coisas diferentes e destinada a usos diferentes.

A principal diferença é que numa classe abstrata você pode ter um misto de métodos abstratos que alguém terá que implementar a consumir a classe e métodos já implementados. Numa interface você somente tem declaração de métodos.

No meu entender classes abstratas devem ser usadas exatamente quando for interessante compartilhar uma implementação com coisas a serem implementadas já interfaces devem ser usadas quando desejamos somente definir um padrão de comunicação entre chamados.

Para saber mais da uma olhada neste link. (inglês)

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/interface-vs-abstract-class/