# Princípio de substituição de Liskov

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, solid, princípio-liskov

O principio de substituição de Liskov diz que se dados tipos `T` e `S` sendo `S` subtipo de `T` então `S` deve poder ser substituído por `T`. Meu entendimento é que se eu tenho uma instância de `S` então eu posso usar ela em lugares nos quais eu usaria instâncias de `T`.

Mas isso me parece que já está naturalmente garantido pela linguagem em si. No caso, trabalho com C# e se eu tenho um tipo `S` que herda de `T` então o seguinte código é totalmente válido

```
S obj = new S();
T objRef = obj;
```

Daí o que acontece é basicamente

- Ao usar `objRef` no lugar de `obj` eu só tenho acesso aos membros de `T`, sendo que os de `S` não são acessíveis.
- Ao chamar um método virtual de `T` a partir de `objRef` se o mesmo tem uma implementação diferente em `S` é essa que é chamada.

De qualquer forma, eu *sempre* posso usar objetos do tipo `S` no lugar de objetos do tipo `T`. Por conta disso, obedecer o principio de substituição de Liskov já não está garantido pela linguagem em si?

Por que esse principio é importante se parece ser algo natural da linguagem?

Comment: Isso, apenas é verdade em termos da verificação que o compilador faz. O que essa verificação não garante é que a lógica implementada numa classe subtipo quebre essa regra. Veja este [poste](http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/solid-part-3-liskov-substitution-interface-segregation-principles--net-36710) onde tem o muito conhecido exemplo do ***rectângulo*** e ***quadrado.***

Comment: **Macoratti tem uma ótima série (vídeos) sobre** [Os Principios SOLID](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhP2_t2Ae_Q&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8) [Neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNC1x8dlsH8&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8&index=3) ele explica o [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNC1x8dlsH8&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8&index=3) com exemplos. Fontes: 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoqYHkQy8q5nEMv1gkcZgSw
http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/pa_solid.htm

Comment: O LSP realmente é algo muito natural se olharmos do ponto de vista de hoje em dia mas não era tão óbvio assim na época (tanto é que acabou ganhando um nome especial). Na época eles tinham acabado de inventar a orientação a objetos e era bastante comum o uso de "herança de implementação" (por exemplo, círculos com elipses ou  pilhas com vetores) que não respeitam a regra da substituição.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) pode ser aplicado em linguagens que não garantem nada. O princípio usa uma abordagem **semântica** e não se preocupa com a implementação disto.

Mesmo as linguagens que garantem alguma coisa só podem garantir que o mecanismo de substituição estará correto e possivelmente o compilador gerará código necessário para facilitar o trabalho do programador que não precisa se preocupar com todos os detalhes.

De fato os compiladores só conseguem identificar se a estrutura do código está em ordem, só conseguem entender o que o código pode dizer a eles. Nada impede que você faça um código em C# em que todos os contratos estão de acordo, a substituição pode ser feita tecnicamente de forma perfeita mas que o código real que implementa o tipo de fato não está substituindo operações de forma equivalente e compatível com o comportamento desejado.

Em geral só um humano pode dizer se aquele código escrito no subtipo corresponde a uma implementação diferente do tipo herdado mas produzindo os resultados desejados em concordância com a intenção original do tipo superior. Considera-se impossível criar uma linguagem que possa garantir isto (até seria possível, mas o custo é grande e exigiria tanta anotação sobre a questão que não deve compensar o esforço).

Algumas linguagens, incluindo C#, permitem que os contratos possam ser verificados não só na assinatura dos métodos mas como os dados serão comunicados com seus chamadores, mas não mais que isto. Na verdade quanto mais rígidos forem esses contratos mais difícil será criar um subtipo compatível.

## Exemplos de violação

Um exemplo claro de violação do princípio que não viola nada na linguagem (sem preocupação de código correto só mostrando o problema):

```
class Produto {
    ...
    public virtual void somaEstoque(int valor) { this.qtde += valor; }
}
class Metal : Produto {
    ....
    public override void somaEstoque(int valor) { this.qtde -= valor; }
```

O exemplo é exagerado mas mostra como é fácil violar o princípio. Você pode fazer o oposto do que se espera sem que a linguagem reclame de nada.

Outra forma de violação é quando você não usa o polimorfismo. A linguagem não tem como saber se você deveria usá-lo ou não.

```
class Arquivo {
    ...
    public virtual void Gerar() { ... }
}
class ArquivoWord : Arquivo {
    ...
    public void GerarDoc() { ... }
}
public class ArquivoPdf : Arquivo {
    public void GerarPdf() { ... }
}
```

Pronto, você não tem substituição alguma aí. Mas deveria. A linguagem não obriga você sobrescrever o método virtual como o problema exige e como ela foi pensada.

Outro exemplo que fere a semântica sem afetar a técnica é quando um método que está na classe ascendente e ele é invalidado na classe descendente:

```
public override void Metodo() { throw NotImplemeted(); }
```

Se a classe mãe definiu esse método no contrato ela queria que algo fosse feito aí. Isto é um forte indicador que a classe filha **não é uma** mãe, que é exatamente o que este princípio fala. As pessoas tendem achar que uma coisa **é um** quando na verdade não é. E aí elas começam descobrir que herança é bem problemática e raramente é útil. E coloca em cheque a utilidade de OOP do ponto de vista pragmático.

## OOP

Não estou dizendo que OOP é um lixo e é um paradigma que não deve ser usado. Eu o uso quando ele traz mais benefícios que malefícios mas na maior parte do tempo uso classes mais para encapsular do que para herdar. Ao contrário da crença dos apaixonados por OOP acham, isso acaba simplificando o *design*.

Por isso as linguagens multi paradigma funcionam e as mono paradigma fracassam. O problema aparece quando o programador acha que as primeiras deveriam ser, e alguns até acham que elas usam apenas um paradigma e forçam o uso de uma só ferramenta para resolver todos os problemas. Eu já fui esse programador quando não tinha experiência, eu me apaixonei por OOP nos anos 80 e levei mais que uma década para perceber que não era saudável. E só aconteceu quando comecei usar OOP na prática e ver que ela era só outra ferramenta com suas vantagens e defeitos e não **a** ferramenta universal que alguns tentavam e ainda tentam vender.

Uma das críticas que se faz à OOP é que ela não consegue reproduzir de fato o mundo real como se promete em algumas definições e nem sempre o reuso de código é tão simples como se vende. Se você definir um tipo de forma muito restrita para alcançar um definição mais precisa você cria problemas para o subtipo ser definido.

É um problema semelhante ao que ocorre em banco de dados onde se prega para restringir o que os "usuários" (aplicações) do banco de dados podem fazer, ou seja, o banco é autossuficiente em todas as regras de uso. Isso é lindo na teoria mas na prática torna muitas aplicações inviáveis. Então a solução é não definir o banco de dados tão bem assim e deixar parte da definição de como o modelo deve ser validado para a aplicação de um jeito diferente de acordo com cada contexto onde o dado está sendo usado. Aí você começa se questionar se o que está no banco de dados deveria estar e até mesmo se, em última análise, não deveria estar tudo na aplicação.

## Problema do círculo e elipse

A dificuldade gerou o [problema do círculo e elipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) onde torna impossível garantir que todos os critérios do tipo e do subtipo sejam satisfeitos ao mesmo tempo.

Em geral define-se que um círculo é um caso especial de uma elipse. Assim como um quadrado é um caso especial de um retângulo. Então vejamos um código usando esta hierarquia:

```
class Retangulo {
    public virtual double Altura { get; set; }
    public virtual double Comprimento { get; set; }
    public double Area { get { return Altura * Comprimento; } }
}
class Quadrado : Retangulo {
    public override double Altura { set { base.Altura = base.Comprimento = value; } }
    public override double Comprimento { set { base.Altura = base.Comprimento = value; } }
}
class Calculos {
    public void MudaArea(Retangulo retangulo) {
        retangulo.Altura *= 2;
        retangulo.Comprimento *= 4;
        //faz alguma coisa
    }
    public void FazCalculo() {
        MudaArea(new Quadrado() { Altura = 2.0, Comprimento = 2.0 };
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/LiskovExamples.cs).

Na definição já vemos um problema. Se altura e comprimento devem ser o mesmo, porque ambos devem existir? A linguagem não reclamou mas semanticamente a definição está errada e viola o LSP.

A coisa fica pior quando as classes são usadas e o código manda um quadrado para um método que muda os valores da altura e comprimento de forma independente. Então o método `MudaArea()` espera fazer uma mudança que não ocorre como deveria. No fundo a área que deveria ser multiplicada por 8 acaba sendo multiplicada por 64. A linguagem não pode fazer nada para impedir essa discrepância.

Mas podemos dizer que o problema começou quando o subtipo tentou estabelecer uma regra própria. E violou a regra do tipo base. Fez a Barbara ter calafrios.

Mas se a definição não garantisse nada sobre a altura e comprimento este problema não aconteceria. Mas aí permitiria que o método transformasse o que seria um quadrado em um retângulo do ponto de vista semântico, embora tecnicamente o código ainda o trataria como se fosse um quadrado. Mais uma vez a linguagem não conseguiu fazer nada.

Tem uma quantidade enorme de formas de mostrar como estas classes podem violar o LSP. Ele poderia, por exemplo introduzir um membro `Lado` e ignorar `Altura` e `Comprimento`. É que exemplos como este ficam mais óbvios - para alguns - que viola o **é um**.

É possível resolver o problema como pode ser visto no artigo da Wikipedia *linkado* acima mas em geral ferirá o LSP. Algumas soluções apresentadas ali podem causar mais problemas ainda. Outras tornam muito difícil pensar em tudo o que pode acontecer, até mesmo ser impossível tratar de tudo. Uma coisa é achar solução para um caso simples e bastante estudado, outra é fazer em problemas gerais complexos do dia a dia.

## Conclusão

No final vemos que um dos problemas do OOP é que é difícil definir os objetos, transpor o [mundo real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) para código. E do ponto de vista de código acabamos descobrindo que o círculo não é uma elipse e quase nada **é um** de fato já que quase tudo pode **incluir** um detalhe incompatível com seu ancestral.

OOP é legal quando simula objetos inventados, que só existem no código mesmo. Por isto ela funciona melhor em GUI ou em jogos que conhecemos - mas não nos jogos inteligentes que desejamos. Mesmo nestes casos pode ser difícil dar todas as garantias semânticas. A vantagem é que podemos fazer simplificações quando inventamos o objeto.

Comment: Quem é Barbara?

Comment: @LINQ Liskov :D

Comment: Tentei encaixar em todos os pedaços do texto, menos no mais óbvio. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

O Princípio de substituição de Liskov (The Liskov Substitution Principle), corresponde a letra **L** da sigla **SOLID** (Abreviatura dos cinco primeiros princípios da programação orientada a objetos e design de código identificados por Robert C. Martin (ou Uncle Bob) por volta do ano 2000.)

> De qualquer forma, eu sempre posso usar objetos do
>   tipo S no lugar de objetos do tipo T. Por conta disso, obedecer o
>   principio de substituição de Liskov já não está garantido pela
>   linguagem em si?
>  Por que esse principio é importante se parece ser
>   algo natural da linguagem?

Com esta afirmação você está tratando o **Princípio de substituição de Liskov** como algo separado dos princípios **SOLID**, e assim pode ferir, por exemplo, o **Principio da Responsabilidade Única** (Uma classe deve ter um, e somente um, motivo para mudar.) ou o **Princípio Aberto-Fechado** (Você deve ser capaz de estender um comportamento de uma classe, sem modificá-lo.).

Lembre-se que o **Princípio de substituição de Liskov** é apenas um dos cinco princípios **SOLID**. A utilização de apenas destes princípios de forma separada não garante um código extensível, coeso e de fácil manutenção.

Segue uma descrição dos princípios **SOLID**:

- **S** - Principio da Responsabilidade Única (The Single Responsibility Principle)

  `- Uma classe deve ter um, e somente um, motivo para mudar.`
- **O** - Princípio Aberto-Fechado (The Open Closed Principle)

  `- Você deve ser capaz de estender um comportamento de uma classe, sem modificá-lo.`
- **L** - Princípio da Substituição de Liskov (The Liskov Substitution Principle)

  `- As classes derivadas devem poder substituir suas classes bases.`
- **I** - Princípio da Segregação da Interface (The Interface Segregation Principle)

  `- Muitas interfaces específicas são melhores do que uma interface geral.`
- **D** - Princípio da inversão da dependência (The Dependency Inversion Principle)

  `- Dependa de uma abstração e não de uma implementação.`

**Macoratti tem uma ótima série (vídeos) sobre** [Os Principios SOLID](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhP2_t2Ae_Q&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8)

[Neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNC1x8dlsH8&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8&index=3) ele explica o [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNC1x8dlsH8&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFHd4ikkfrMe6O3WVpaWvjW8&index=3) com exemplos.

Fontes: 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoqYHkQy8q5nEMv1gkcZgSw
http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/pa_solid.htm
http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/orientacao-a-objeto-solid/

Comment: Você acha que isto responde ao que foi perguntado? Dá uma relida na pergunta, basicamente o que você postou é o que o AP já sabia sobre o assunto.

Comment: Penso que pode contribuir para o entendimento principalmente para quem não endente estes princípios ou está aprendendo (como eu). Caso não pense deste modo pode excluir @bigown :)

Comment: Não é questão de excluir, negativar ou algo assim, a informação é interessante e está correta mas não responde o foco da pergunta dele. Ele sabe o que é SOLID e sabe o que é LSP, ele só não entende porque precisa seguir isto se a linguagem C# já "garante" isto.

Comment: Concordo com seu ponto de vista. Meu intuito com esta resposta foi contribuir para discussão e alertar os que estão aprendendo os princípios SOLID. @bigown

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, tua resposta é muito boa, mas no contexto errado, eu te sugiro remover a tua resposta e colocá-la em outro post que pergunte o que é SOLID, não pesquisei, mas certamente há aqui no SOP