# Sobrescrever métodos com base apenas no nome

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, método

Estou criando uma classe base abstrata para prover um padrão para outras classes.

Os métodos da classe base devem ser sobrescritos na classe derivada.

Agora vem o pulo do gato. A sobrescrita deve acontecer somente baseada no nome do método, sem levar em consideração os parâmetros.

Exemplo:

```
public abstrac class A
{
    public int AnyMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ( "This method is not implemented" );
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override int AnyMethod( int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Como podem ver, minha ideia é sobrescrever um método da classe base independente dos parâmetros, ou seja, apenas baseado no nome do método.

Isso é possível?

Comment: No caso, B herda A?

Comment: Sim, acabei de modificar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, isso não é possível, [o método não é composto só por seu nome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Sempre que a assinatura do método for diferente ele é outro método. Aí há [sobrecarga de método](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) (que é bem comum, mais que a sobrecarga de operador). O próprio exemplo colocado lá mostra que não, já que não tem `override`.

Claro que tem maneiras de atingir um objetivo semelhante passando por cima de linguagem se fosse algo realmente necessário, mas se for para fazer isso é melhor usar outra linguagem, do que criar um mecanismo sofisticado para contornar o que a linguagem impede propositalmente.

Pra falar a verdade nem deveria usar herança se deseja que o método tenha parâmetros diferentes, porque na prática [eles fazem coisas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), então herança, ou pelo menos o polimorfismo, é o mecanismo errado.

O que dá para fazer, dependendo do caso, é usar um método público com assinatura igual para a herança e ter métodos privados para ter uma implementação mais apropriada em cada classe, aí o método público herdado chamaria o privado com assinatura diferente. Ou pode-se pensar em algum outro mecanismo que use algo parecido.

Eu diria que todos seriam gambiarras para contornar a filosofia da linguagem. Só não faço uma afirmação categórica porque não sei o caso concreto. Em algum caso bem específico é possível que alguma solução assim possa ser usada sem problemas. Nesse exemplo demonstrado não parece adequado porque o método está fazendo uma soma de dois operandos.

Note que usar outra assinatura, como `params`, está fazendo algo diferente do que pede a pergunta, ou seja foi mudada a assinatura para que o `override` ocorra baseado no todo e não apenas no nome. Há uma [diferença entre parâmetros e argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

O uso do [modificador `new`, que não faz a sobrescrita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101), não tem a menor serventia para esse problema já que ele só esconderia o método base que tem a mesma assinatura, em um método de assinatura diferente seu uso é desnecessário e o funcionamento é exatamente o mesmo sem o modificador, afinal esse é um método novo por definição.

Lançar uma `NotImplementedException` raramente é uma boa ideia, certamente não é em um método que serve de base.

Ignorei pequenos erros que talvez existam só no exemplo, obviamente eles não serão cometidos no caso concreto, nem compilaria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso, teremos que ser criativos. Simplesmente ignorar os argumentos extrapola o design da linguagem C#.

Primeiro, o método, para ser sobrescrito, precisa ser `virtual`:

```
public virtual int AnyMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException ( "This method is not implemented" );
}
```

Segundo, é possível fazer uma implementação que receba N argumentos de um tipo determinado. Ou, ainda, de `object`, mas isso se você gosta de viver com emoção:

```
public virtual int AnyMethod(params int[] numeros)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException ( "This method is not implemented" );
}
```

Terceiro, você pode sim ir derivando polimorfismos com argumentos diferentes na classe derivada. Algo assim:

```
public class B: A
{
    public override int AnyMethod(params int[] lista)
    {
        return lista.Sum(x => x);
    }

    public int AnyMethod(int a, int b) 
    {
        return AnyMethod(new int[] {a, b});
    }
}
```

Aí poderemos ter um método específico com 2 argumentos e outro com N.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new B().AnyMethod(1, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(new B().AnyMethod(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle pra você](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aa4uWb).

---

A pedido do autor da pergunta, também irei explicar mais uma opção, que é a [reintrodução de métodos, feita pela palavra modificadora `new` no método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx).

`new` seria o equivalente do `reintroduce` do Delphi, em que sobrescrevemos explicitamente um método da classe base na classe derivada. A diferença para `override` é que o método da classe base é pode ser chamado usando `base.AnyMethod`, enquanto que usando `new` o método da classe base é totalmente ignorado.

No escopo do exemplo, se houvesse um método `public int AnyMethod(int a, int b)` na classe base, seria algo como:

```
public new int AnyMethod(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Este tipo de operador, assim como a adição de mais polimorfismos em classes derivadas, pode ser prevenida usando [o modificador `sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/88c54tsw.aspx) na declaração de classe.

Atualizei o Fiddle colocando agora um polimorfismo para três operadores.

Comment: Então, também postei essa pergunta no forum MSDN, e tive um resposta interessante.
Alguém conhecia essa [solução](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/a795d14e-6c9b-4492-8740-a178b2769320/sobrescrever-mtodos-com-base-apenas-no-nome?forum=vscsharppt)? Procede?

Comment: Sim, isto é o que se chama "reintrodução de método". Se quiser, posso expandir esta resposta explicando isto melhor.

Comment: Opa, claro, sempre prefiro as respostas aqui do stack, pois acho a turma aqui mais paciente. E as respostas sempre são mais detalhadas.

Comment: Resposta e Fiddle atualizados. Se precisar de mais detalhes, é só falar.

Comment: No exemplo MSDN o autor reintroduz um método da classe base, mas na nova versão ele acrescenta dois parâmetros ao método que não existe na versão da classe base.
Nesse caso, o modificador new está realmente sobrescrevendo o método herdado ou está apenas criando uma sobrecarga?

Comment: Na resposta dele, o modificador new é desnecessário. Se você experimentar modificar o Fiddle para deixar parecido, verá que o Fiddle irá avisá-lo que o modificador `new` não é necessário. Portanto, ele está apenas criando um polimorfismo para o método. Quando falamos em sobrecarga, estamos falando de operadores, e não exatamente de métodos.