# Erro Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override C#

Tags: c#, .net, sobrecarga, sobrescrita

> [image: Já alterei o namespace, a classe está com o mesmo nome, porém continua o mesmo erro. Já não sei o que trocar]

Já verifiquei em outros fóruns e até aqui mesmo, porém está tudo **correto** com o nome da classe o `namespace` está do mesmo jeito.

Ele me ocasionou outros erros além desse, porém esse eu acredito que seja o principal que esteja fazendo ocorrer os outros.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0115 'Emitentes.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override
>   Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0115  'Emitentes.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Você está sobrepondo um método da classe onde está sendo implementada, porém não há classe a ser implementada, portanto, não há quem sobrepor.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Vou seguir o tour, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Quando você dá um [`override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139880/101) significa que esta implementação irá substituir outra já existente do mesmo método ([mesma assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)) que vem da classe ou interface que esta classe está herdando. Porém em seu código a classe não está fazendo herança e por isso não pode sobrescrever nada, ele não acha um método para sobrescrever.

Pelo menos é isso que dá pra inferir, pode ser que falte contexto na pergunta  para identificar algum outro problema.

Talvez esteja em outro arquivo desse `partial`, mas a declaração da classe precisa ser igual em todos arquivos.

Este método pertence à interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) então é pelo menos ela que deve herdar.

Outros erros podem ou não estar relacionados com isto ou com outras heranças, corrigindo este fará aparecer outros.

Porém eu fico preocupado porque esse erro é básico e este código está fazendo algo bastante sofisticado. Muitos problemas podem estar acontecendo aí sem dar erro e seu código não será confiável sem entender tudo sobre ele. Reflita sobre o perigo que está correndo.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Emitentes' does not contain a definition for 'ResumeLayout' and no extension method 'ResumeLayout' accepting a first argument of type 'Emitentes' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Ele trás esse erro no Resume Layout.

Comment: Sim, vai aparecer um erro atrás do outro, é o que eu falei, eu resolvi o que você postou. E vai aparecer vários outros porque cada vez fica mais claro que você está usando um código sem saber o que significa cada palavra dele, isso não dá certo.