# Método com generics em tipo herdado

Tags: java, genéricos

Como faço para usar dois tipos no método *generics*, para somar apenas as áreas das classes `Quadrado` e `Retangulo`.

Tentei um método como esse:

```
public static double soma(Forma <? extends Quadrado> elementos) {


        return elementos.getArea();

    }
```

e `Forma` e `abstract`.

Comment: Fale mais sobre as classes `Forma`, `Quadrado` e `Retangulo`. Quais são os métodos delas? A solução que eu bolaria simplesmente não usaria nenhum tipo genérico, então gostaria de ver as suas classes para entender o que são e o que representam esses tipos genéricos.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível em Java.

`Quadrado` e `Retangulo` herdam de `Forma`? Ou um herda do outro? Bom, se for isso, [é um erro clássico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Mas vamos considerar o primeiro.

```
public static <T extends Forma> double soma(T elementos) {
    return elementos.getArea();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/GenericsInheritance.java).

O que deve fazer dentro do método eu não sei já que não há informação sobre isso.

Comment: E onde é que há alguma coisa sendo somada no método `soma`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu respondi sobre o problema que é claro, talvez devesse fechar a pergunta como não clara.

Comment: Eu já dei o primeiro voto de fechamento.