# É incorreto mudar os argumentos em uma classes estendida no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, parâmetros, polimorfismo

É incorreto (ou "semanticamente incorreto") mudar os argumentos em uma classes estendida no PHP?

Por exemplo eu criei esta classe:

```
class Bar
{
    public function __construct($message, $code, $timer)
    {
        var_dump($message, $code);
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar
{
    public function __construct($message)
    {

        parent::__construct($message, 0, time());
    }
}
```

Então chamo assim:

```
Foo('Error Processing Request');
```

Isto seria incorreto?

Comment: Não... nada de errado nisso.

Comment: Por que o downvote? Não é uma pergunta valida, será que poderia explicar o motivo, não se preocupe não sou vingativo, não vou devolver downvotes, eu só quero saber aonde esta o problema da pergunta para tentar melhora-la

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Em construtor não há problema** algum porque efetivamente não há polimorfismo nele. Você só pode chamar o construtor da classe específica que deseja, não tem porque ter polimorfismo nesse caso.

Só precisa verificar se não está ferindo o [princípio de substituição Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Um tipo derivado não pode modificar as restrições que não existiam no tipo original, a substituição precisa ser perfeita. Mas aí é uma análise que depende de forte contexto e envolve todo o tipo.

O mesmo vale para qualquer método que não deseja o polimorfismo. O problema vai ocorrer nos métodos polimórficos.

## Métodos polimórficos

Vamos dizer que tenha um método `m` em `Bar` com três parâmetros, e em `Foo` esse método tem apenas um parâmetro.

Pensa que você cria uma função que deve receber um `Bar`. Obviamente pode enviar um `Foo` para ela já que todo `Foo` é um `Bar`. Nessa função você chama `m` passando 3 argumentos. Mas o `m` que será chamado é o do `Foo` que só tem 1 parâmetro. 2 parâmetros serão descartados e não produzirá o que espera.

```
function m(Bar $x) {
    $x->m('Error Processing Request', 10, 1000000000);
}
class Bar {
    public function m($message, $code, $timer) {
        echo "Bar\n";
        var_dump($message, $code, $timer);
    }
}
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function m($message) {
       echo "Foo\n";
       parent::m($message, 0, time());
    }
}
m(new Foo);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VQq9gD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xwvqhthe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Polymorphism.php). Note que este código tem *warnings* dependendo da versão.

Então este caso é semanticamente errado.

Você pode pensar que se for o oposto pode funcionar.

```
function m(Bar $x) {
    $x->m('Error Processing Request');
}
class Bar {
    public function m($message) {
        echo "Bar\n";
        var_dump($message);
    }
}
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function m($message, $code, $timer) {
        var_dump($code, $timer);
        echo "Foo\n";
        parent::m($message);
    }
}
m(new Foo);
```

Veja [não funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BVzzcY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qviqfexu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Polymorphism2.php).

Era o que deseja? Acho que não. É semanticamente errado.

Pode existir alguma situação que é correto? Acho que pode, mas provavelmente nem era para ter polimorfismo ali. O polimorfismo pressupõe que há uma substituição perfeita.

Comment: Esperou até as 22:00 pra ganhar o chapéu hehehe :)

Comment: foi antes, pode ver.