# O que é generalização e especialização?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Em POO, o que é o que é generalização e especialização? Teria alguma explicação em alguma maneira técnica e uma maneira não tão técnica? Mais simples de entender, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nada melhor para explicar isso como um exemplo, veja o abaixo:

```
Veiculo {
    function locomover()

    function parar()

    function ligarLanternas()
}

Carro extends Veiculo
{
    function travarPortas()

    function abrirVidros()
}

Moto extends Veiculo
{
    //Nenhuma particularidade
}
```

Veiculo seria uma **generalização** de uma classe que compõem metodos e atributos em comum entre carro e moto.

Carro seria uma **especificação** de **veiculo**, pois alem de herdar os componentes ainda especifica novas funções e atributos.

Podemos então dizer que um carro e uma moto podem se *locomover*, *parar* e *ligar as lanternas*, mas somente o carro consegue *travar as portas* e *abrir os vidros*.

Em resumo, generalização seria uma *abstração* entre classes que exercem funções parecidas. Enquanto a especificação é de fato uma especificação dessa classe que foi abstraida (Ou mesmo de uma classe semelhante, que possua as mesmas funções).

**Keywords**: *herança*, *composição*

Answer (score 6):

Podemos falar do termo em diversos em contextos, mesmo se nos atermos à orientação a objeto pelo menos em duas situações pode ser usadas.

Na herança a resposta aceita já diz bem o que é.

A generalização é uma forma **geral** de definir uma classe, é colocar os membros de estado e comportamento que todos os objetos que se conformem com aquela especificação devem ter, não importa se ele seja de um tipo mais **específico**. Ou seja, ali consta as características essenciais de um grupo de classes que possuem algo em comum. Por definição o que é mais geral é uma classe base, uma classe mãe.

A especialização é por definição uma classe derivada, filha. Ela possui características que só dizem respeita àquela classe. Ali há membros que são **especiais** para aquela classe.

O [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) explica bem sobre o fato de um objeto especializado ter que ser o mesmo que um objeto generalizado.

Então uma banana é uma especialização de uma fruta. Em fruta temos tudo o que precisamos saber sobre qualquer fruta. Não pode ter nada especial ali sobre uma fruta específica. Em banana temos informações que só dizem respeito à banana.

Uma classe pose ser tanto generalizada quanto especializada.

Uma classe animal pode ser só generalizada, mas uma classe mamífero pode ser: a) generalizada porque possui características que todos os mamíferos **em geral** possuem, assim como sua classe base possui características que todos os animais **em geral** possuem, mas possui também características **especiais** que só os mamíferos possuem; então b) ela é uma especialização de animal. Poderíamos dizer que uma classe cavalo poderia ser só especializada já que ela deriva de mamífero, possui suas características, mais as próprias que são especiais.

Em alguns casos a especialização pode ser esperada, mas não adequada. No *link* acima mostro que é tentador considerar que um retângulo é uma especialização de quadrado, mas por algum detalhe na verdade não é. Há uma situação na classe que não se pode garantir que todos os preceitos gerais estabelecidos na classe base sejam completamente conformados na classe derivada, portanto não há especialização naquela relação. E esse é um dos motivos porque herança nem sempre é uma boa ideia. Muitas vezes enxergamos algo como uma relação de generalização e especialização quando não é, ou um dia pode deixar de vir a ser.

Claro que poderia haver novas especializações de raças de cavalos. A única forma de garantir que uma classe só será especializada é se proibir que a classe seja derivada. Nem todas linguagens possuem esse recurso. E a única forma de garantir que uma classe será a generalização de de outra classe é garantindo que ela será abstrata, ou seja, não pode ser instanciada diretamente.

Mas em polimorfismo podemos usar os termos também. Se você possui um método em uma classe geral, podemos chamar este método de generalizado, e o método polimórfico na classe específica é o método especializado. Cada um terá sua própria implementação, possivelmente o método especializado chamando o generalizado para complementar sua execução. Então em situações polimórficas o método especializado **substitui** o método generalizado normalmente esperado.

```
class Veiculo {
    locomover() { ... } 
    parar() { ... } 
    ligarLanternas() { ... } 
}

class Carro extends Veiculo {
    travarPortas() { ... } //especialização porque é característica própria

    locomover() { ... } //especialização porque o comportamento é próprio
    parar() { ... } //tudo aqui é diferente do implementado na classe generalizada
    //note que ligarLanternas() não foi especializado, o comportamento é o geral mesmo
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Specialization.java).

Então não é só o carro que é uma especialização de veículo, a locomoção do carro também é uma especialização da locomoção do veículo. Inclusive pode ser que em outro exemplo a locomoção de veículo seja só um contrato sem uma implementação deixando a cargo do carro resolver isto.

A generalização pode ser considerada uma intersecção de todas as classes especializadas que ela seja base. E esse é o problema, nem sempre podemos saber todas as derivadas, então pode ser que as derivadas acabem possuindo especializações que no fundo são gerais, mas só depois é que descobrimos, tarde demais para arrumar. Pior ainda é quando acreditamos que algo é geral quando pode ser específico, ferindo o princípio de Liskov. Tudo funciona lindamente quando temos total controle sobre todo o código, mas traz problemas quando isso não ocorre. E orientação a objeto é usado primordialmente para gerenciar manutenção. Curiosamente a composição acaba sendo um mecanismo mais flexível, ainda que também tenha seus problemas. Não adianta, qualquer coisa que pode mudar pode trazer um desafio não importa a metodologia adotada.

Entenda que interfaces e *traits* não deixam de ser generalizações também, não é só sobre classes. Um contrato é uma generalização cuja implementação é uma especialização.