# Dúvida de concurso sobre herança e polimorfismo em orientação a objetos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Fiz a prova do concurso do IFNMG para o cargo de professor de informática. A banca que elaborou a prova foi a Fundação CEFET. Uma das questões foi a seguinte:

> Sobre as afirmativas abaixo, relacionadas aos conceitos da programação
>   orientada a objetos, é correto afirmar que ao
>
> a) instanciar um objeto de uma classe abstrata, só é possível acessar
>   seus atributos definidos como public.
>  b) definir um atributo como
>   static, em uma classe, só é possível ter acesso a ele após haver, pelo
>   menos, um objeto instanciado dessa mesma classe.
>  c) declarar em
>   uma classe um método abstract, todas as classes que herdam dessa
>   classe para instanciar objetos são obrigadas a implementar esse
>   método.
>  d) definir, em uma classe base de uma hierarquia de
>   classes, um método com o modificador final, em uma classe filha, esse
>   mesmo método só poderá ser sobrescrito com a visibilidade public.
>   e) definir, em uma classe base de uma hierarquia de classes, um método
>   com a visibilidade protected, em uma classe filha, esse mesmo método
>   só poderá ser sobrescrito como protected ou private.

Acabei marcando a letra E, pois fiquei em dúvida entre C e E. **O gabarito diz que o correto é a letra C**.

A letra E não está correta também?

Existe algo errado nesta questão que possa ser passível de recurso?

Comment: A E está errada mesmo. Devido à substituição de Liskov, você não poderia reduzir visibilidade, apenas aumentar. Vou tentar melhorar esse comentário como resposta ou procurar duplicatas (acho que já vi essa questão aqui)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23081702/2241463

Comment: Engano meu, não há duplicata. Foi outra questão de concurso do tipo "marque a certa", mas consegui encontrá-la com palavras chaves de OO

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> a) instanciar um objeto de uma classe abstrata, só é possível acessar seus atributos definidos como public.

Não é possível instanciar uma classe abstrata.

> b) definir um atributo como static, em uma classe, só é possível ter acesso a ele após haver, pelo menos, um objeto instanciado dessa mesma classe.

Um "atributo" estático pertence à classe e não à instância, portanto pode ser acessado em qualquer momento, mesmo sem existir instâncias desta classe.

> c) declarar em uma classe um método abstract, todas as classes que herdam dessa classe para instanciar objetos são obrigadas a implementar esse método.

Exatamente, um método abstrato não tem implementação, portanto não pode ser instanciado. Classes que herdam dele precisam implementá-lo, caso contrário a classe herdada precisa ser abstrata também, o que a impedirá de ser instanciada.

> d) definir, em uma classe base de uma hierarquia de classes, um método com o modificador final, em uma classe filha, esse mesmo método só poderá ser sobrescrito com a visibilidade public.

`final` indica que não haverá sobreposição do método então todo o resto da afirmação está incorreto.

> e) definir, em uma classe base de uma hierarquia de classes, um método com a visibilidade protected, em uma classe filha, esse mesmo método só poderá ser sobrescrito como protected ou private.

Pode ser `protected` ou `public`. Acho que o primeiro é óbvio que pode. Assim como uma classe filha pode ter novos membros que não tinha na mãe fica claro que um método existente com uma visibilidade restrita pode aparecer com uma visibilidade mais liberal, ou seja, é como se fosse um membro novo com visibilidade total, a `public`. Isso já demonstra um erro na pergunta. Mas o contrário indica mais erro ainda. Uma classe filha não pode deixar de ter um membro que existia na classe mãe, para **ser um** objeto igual à mãe ele precisa ter tudo o que já existia antes. Quando você diminui a visibilidade você faz com um membro que era bastante visível não seja visível em todas situações, portanto é comum se esse membro deixasse de existir em certos cenários, o que tornaria o objeto incompatível com o que se espera dele. Isto é definido formalmente pelo [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

Mas além disso, o polimorfismo só faz sentido em membros `protected` e `public`, um membro privado por definição é um detalhes de implementação e só pertence à classe em que ela foi definida, não pode passar para outra, neste caso até mesmo na classe mãe isto seria um problema.

Se não existisse o polimorfismo poderia fazer isso porque seriam métodos distintos e aí Liskov não se aplica. Mas a existência da apalavra *sobrescrito* no texto deixa claro que há polimorfismo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).