# Como alterar nível de acesso de propriedade em uma herança?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança, propriedade, visibilidade

Eu tenho uma classe que quando herdada quero que um de seus atributos de público se torne privado, para que o usuário não tenho acesso ao uso dessa variável nessa classe, mas não sei como fazer isso.

```
public class Pai {
   public string Exemplo {get; set;}
}

public class Filho : Pai {
   private string Exemplo {get; set;}
}

var pai = new Pai() {
   Exemplo = "OK" // funciona
}

var pai = new Filho() {
   Exemplo = "OK" // não funciona
}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer esse feito? Eu estava vendo a *keyword* `internal`, que poderia ser utilizada nesse caso, pois estou fazendo um SDK, mas se eu utilizar ela na `Pai`, o usuário também não conseguira acessar essa propriedade no `Pai` e queria que isso fosse possível.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível, ponto. Tentaram dar uma solução, mas ela não existe. Uma vez o campo ([e não atributo, este termo está errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), mas é pior porque isso não é nem mesmo um campo é uma propriedade) declarado como público é impossível diminuir sua visibilidade nas classes herdadas. Classes que herdam devem ter toda API pública da classe herdada, nada menos, o que está tentando fazer é eliminar o que já existia na classe, por isso quebra a herança, então se quer fazer isto, é porque [não deve usar herança aí](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), simples assim.

A pergunta não ajuda muito porque tem um exemplo abstrato e modelar corretamente em exemplo abstrato nunca dá certo, em um caso real poderíamos ver alguma outra solução ou identificar qual é o problema real.

Porém o que fica claro é que se um campo deve ser público na classe mais geral e ter um acesso mais restrito na classe mais específica herança é o mecanismo errado. Não pode por `protected` porque além de mudar a visibilidade original desejada ainda não torna privada depois. E não pode substituir a propriedade por uma nova porque aí não está respeitando o polimorfismo, embora isto poderia ser uma solução em algum caso específico onde não se quer a herança mesmo, provavelmente não quer isso (quase todo uso do modificador `new` em um método é errado, ele foi criado para situações bem extraordinárias), só com o caso concreto poderíamos afirmar se o `new` serve, mas reforço que quase nunca serve.

Em algum cenário talvez fosse o caso de criar outro campo ou propriedade que seja privado deixando esse que já é público de lado, mas também acho que neste caso está usando herança equivocadamente.

Uma gambiarra da grossa possível é fazer o método na classe filha lançar uma [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e obrigar fazer de outra forma, mas está obviamente errado. Não digo que nunca deva fazer algo errado, mas precisa justificar bem, não pode fazer porque é mais fácil ou porque não sabe fazer de outra forma. O fácil de hoje é a dificuldade de amanhã.

Programar orientado a objeto é sobre modelar corretamente, só tem vantagem se respeitar como o modelo real de fato é, se inventar maluquices para digitar menos código e associar coisas que não devem ser associadas está trazendo mais problema para seu código não melhoria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Você não pode fazer isso.

Em C#, quando um método tem uma assinatura pública, é obrigatório o uso público dele, independente de sua sobrecarga.

Você pode sobrecarregar um método com o mesmo nome na classe filho usando a instrução `new`. Dessa forma, a declaração do membro irá sobrepor o que está sendo herdado da classe pai se a declaração for pública.

Dessa forma, você irá derivar `Exemplo` mas não irá utilizar a mesma assinatura da classe `Pai`. Você ainda pode acessar `Pai.Exemplo` da sua classe derivada quando usando o assessor `base`.

As chamadas devem ser compatíveis com o nível de acesso. Você não pode acessar o `private` de outra classe que não é a sua. Neste exemplo abaixo, `ExemploHerdado()` irá retornar o que foi definido em seu assessor público.

```
public class Pai {
    public string Exemplo {get; set;}
}

public class Filho : Pai {
    private new string Exemplo {get => "Teste";}
    
    public string ExemploHerdado { get {
            return this.Exemplo; // Acessa Pai.Exemplo, pois ele é público e o método também é
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Pai x = new Pai();
    x.Exemplo = "Olá, mundo";
    
    Filho y = new Filho();
    y.Exemplo = "Foo, bar";
    
    Console.WriteLine(x.Exemplo);
    Console.WriteLine(y.Exemplo);
    Console.WriteLine(y.ExemploHerdado);
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AiSk8A).</sup>

No exemplo acima, `y.Exemplo` chama o método `Pai.Exemplo` porque o que foi definido em `Filho` é privado. Nem é uma sobrecarga porque a assinatura do acesso é diferente. Você não pode acessar um método privado de uma classe que não seja a sua, então, você chama o que está público.

Quando chamo `Filho.ExemploHerdado`, eu retorno a propriedade redeclarada e privada `Exemplo`, com o valor que defini.

Causaria confusão e iria infringir a semântica de segurança de classes se isso fosse possível. Você não gostaria de declarar um método privado e que o mesmo fosse utilizado como público em uma classe herdeira. O mesmo acontece ao contrário.

É bom que exista essa obrigatoriedade porque é um contrato indicando que você deverá utilizar o método daquele jeito em que foi originalmente declarado, e não de outra forma de implementação em que for utilizado.

A [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) também explica bem isso.

Answer (score 2):

Na classe Pai, Atributo nesse caso deve ser Protegido (Protected). Isso faz com que o Filho acesse, mas de fora da classe isso não é possível, apenas para uso interno.

```
public class Pai {
   protected string Exemplo {get; set;}
}
```

Na classe Filho, não há a necessidade de repetição do atributo, pois a herança serve exatamente para isso.

```
public class Filho : Pai {

}
```