# Funções com retorno diferente em Go

Tags: método, interface, golang

Eu preciso criar uma interface que contenha um método `decode()`, mas eu preciso que ele retorne coisas diferentes para cada struct que usar esse método, e eu não sei fazer isso.

```
type teste interface {
    x()
}

type A struct {
}

type B struct {
}

func (a A) x() int{
    return 2
}

func (b B) x() string{
    return "b"
}

func main(){
    var t, tt teste
    t = A{}
    tt = B{}
    fmt.Println(t.x(), tt.x())
}
```

numa hora ele deveria retornar `int` e na outra uma `string`, mas isso não funciona. Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A declaração do método na interface conforme mostrada é uma sintaxe inválida, você precisa declarar toda a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). E fazendo isso só poderá se conformar com a interface se implementar um método que seja exatamente igual ao da interface, não pode ter diferença.

Go não tem isso. Ainda mais por não ter herança e assim covariância, no caso do tipo de retorno.

Mas se pensar conceitualmente, na forma apresentada na pergunta, nem faz sentido, são realmente métodos diferentes sem relação um com outro, mesmo que ache que tem, é só um erro de avaliação (e olha que estou observando um exemplo artificial e já percebi isso).

Não é que seja totalmente impossível construir algo assim, mas teria que usar um mecanismo complexo que cria um objeto que pode conter qualquer um desses dados. Em geral não compensa, cria outros problemas, e se precisar mesmo disto pode ser um indicativo que está usando a linguagem errada para a tarefa, mas falo isso apenas hipoteticamente.

O certo parece que é ter duas interfaces diferentes. Interfaces devem ser o contrato para a mesma coisa, se o resultado produzido não é o mesmo então a interface não é a mesma. Pode ver mais em [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

É possível que tenha até outros erros conceituais, mas a pergunta tratou de forma abstrata demais para falar sobre.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).