# É possível herdar um conjunto limitado de métodos de uma super classe em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Eu gostaria de construir uma classe que herde apenas alguns métodos da classe mãe, mas não todos. Para entender o que estou querendo dizer, suponha que eu tenha duas classes, `Person` e `Student`:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname

    def name_double(self):
        return 2*self.firstname

class Student(Person):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    person=Person("Alan", "Turing")
    student=Student("William","Gosset")
    print(person)
    print(person.name_double())
    print(student)
    print(student.name_double())
```

Meu objetivo é que a classe Student herde apenas os métodos `__init__` e `__str__` da classe Person, mas não `name_double`. O que tentei, em relação à classe `__init__` foi usar:

```py
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        Person.__init__(self, fname, lname)
```

Eu achei que dessa forma a classe Student herdaria apenas o método `__init__` da classe `Person`, mas não foi o que ocorreu. Quando rodo o programa acima com a devida substituição na classe `Student`, o resultado é o mesmo:

```
Alan
AlanAlan
William
WilliamWilliam
```

É possível herdar métodos seletivamente sem precisar fazer uma outra classe?

Comment: *É possível herdar métodos seletivamente sem precisar fazer uma outra classe?* NÃO! Você pode criar um ancestral comum que contenha apenas determinados métodos a serem herdados por todos os descendentes. Agora como está querendo fazer a modelagem de estudante e pessoa está estranha, pois dá a entender que deseja fazer com o que um estudante não seja uma pessoa, pois por mais idiota que pareça essa minha observação ela afeta o desenvolvimento do código e chegando as vezes impedir o desenvolvimento lógico forçando ao uso de gambiarras para continuar a produzir.

Comment: Talvez o conceito de mixins possa lhe ser útil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, isso não faz sentido.

Quando você herda algo está dizendo que quer aquilo que existe. Se não quer aquilo então não herde. A herança faz você assumir todos os contratos já existentes na classe base.

Se é algo que não tem controle. esquece isso, se é algo que você criou e vai usar. o *design* está errado, provavelmente deveria ter classes menores fazendo menos coisas.

Mas aí vem outro problema porque para juntar tudo precisaria de mecanismos apropriados que Python não tem.

Isso está explicado em [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Nem sempre algo deve ter herança, ou se deve ter deve haver um sentido naquilo.

E duas cosias me veem à mente: ao contrário da crença popular, Python não é simples e poderoso como as pessoas andam achando, ela é boa para coisas simples, se precisa mais que isso Python é a linguagem errada, dá muito trabalho fazer certo e ela deixa de ser simples e produtiva; e quando começa ter que fazer algo mais granular então orientação a objeto provavelmente é a técnica errada para aplicar.

E outra coisa que eu falo sempre: exemplos artificiais são bons para explicar mecanismos, mas são péssimos para ensinar *design*. A maioria das pessoas aprendem errado porque ensinam *design* com exemplo artificiais.

Se não quer herdar uma classe em classes que não podem ter um método, então esse método não deve estar na classe superior. Essa é uma solução.

Outra solução é ter esse método sim, qual o problema da classe herdada ter? Pode ser algo mal definido.

A classe base é um mínimo denominador comum. Se algo ali não é comum para tudo que será herdado, está errado. Ou então não deve ter relação de herança entre essas classes.

Mas também pensa se a classe base define bem o que é uma pessoa. Artificialmente sim, mas concretamente é provável que não, então está treinando o erro.