# Quais as diferenças entre modificadores public, private, protected e abstract no Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Quais as diferenças entre eles? Tem alguma regra de herança/polimorfismo relevante para cada um desses modificadores?

Comment: Antes de apresentarem resposta seria bom ler [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89272/137387) que apesar de ser escrita em java esclarece a respeito dos **Modificadores de Acesso** `public`, `private` e `protected`. Para o **Modificador de Não Acesso** `abstract` seria bom ler [O que é e para que serve uma classe abstrata?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/137387) e [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3603/classe-abstrata-x-interface?rq=1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Modificadores de acesso são para controlar o comportamento de acesso externo a essas propriedades:

**Public**: Modificador default, pode ser acessado pela mesma classe, classes filhas e outras classes.

**Private**: Pode ser acessado somente pela própria classe.

**Protected**: Pode ser acessado pela mesma classe e classes filhas.

Sugiro essa [leitura](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-typescript/36729) que aprofunda sobre modificadores de acesso e conceitos importantes de POO

**PS:** Abstract não conheço como modificador de acesso, e também não encontrei referências.

Answer (score -2):

Public (+)
Deixa nossos atributos expostos. Torna visível em todo projeto.
Utilizada apenas quando desejamos que outras classes ‘enxerguem’ nossa classe, método ou atributo.
Os MÉTODOS, sempre que possível, não devem ser públicos, mas normalmente são. *(é a visibilidade padrão em TS.);

Private (-)
Utilizar sempre que possível.
Torna a visibilidade apenas local(mesma classe).
Torna invisível para outras classes. Ninguém fora da classe vai poder acessar atributos, métodos etc..
ATRIBUTOS, se possível, sempre privados.
MÉTODOS que implementam rotinas internas (métodos auxiliares) devem ser privados.

Protected (#)
Visível por classes herdadas
Utilizado eventualmente quando trabalhamos com herança.